# Pyspark AES 256 decryption(Mode_CFB) length error but it works in normal python 3

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, aes

I am trying to decrypt the string that is encrypted via Go/java code. I start getting length errors as soon as I add spark context to it. Can someone please help. I am adding code snippet

````
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def decrypt(key, enc):
    rawCiphertext = base64.b64decode(enc)
    iv=rawCiphertext[:16]
    rawCiphertext_b= rawCiphertext[16:]
    cipher = AES.new(key.encode("utf8"), AES.MODE_CFB, iv,segment_size=128)
    decodedtext = cipher.decrypt(rawCiphertext_b)
    return decodedtext

encrypted = '####'
keyraw = '####'
decrypted = decrypt(keyraw , encrypted)
print(decrypted)```

----> just adding a spark context starts giving me error mentioned below 

```An error was encountered:
Input strings must be a multiple of the segment size 16 in length
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 23, in decrypt
  File "/home/hadoop/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py", line 295, in decrypt
    return self._cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)
ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of the segment size 16 in length```
````

Comment: This reminds me of an unfixed bug for the CFB mode in the legacy PyCrypto library with the same error message, which is fixed in the PyCryptodome library. In this bug, the plaintext length must be an integer multiple of the segment size, so in the posted example 16 bytes (=128 bits). This is a bug because CFB is a stream cipher mode that can handle an _arbitrary_ plaintext length. I am not familiar with Spark/PySpark, but can it be that in the problem environment PyCrypto is used and in the working one PyCryptodome?

Comment: @Topaco Basically I am not able to use pycrypto library still because of the length issue. I most probably have figured out the issue, will update here as soon as I am done with testing.

Comment: The library had issues. Use pycryptodome instead of crypto.